# Weird behaviour setting tableView row height and scrollPosition Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In the same `viewController` I have a `calendarTableView`that represent the month's days. At `cellForRowAt`i select the row corresponding to current day and call a function to populate `timeSlotCollectionView`. It all work but I have a little strange situation.

Case 1: Row `height` = auto and `scrollPosition.none` = `timeSlotCollectionView` don't follow `cornerRadius`

Case2: Row `height` = auto and `scrollPosition.middle` = Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x659ef4) on `calendarTableView`cell definition

Case3: Row `height` = 44 and scrollPosition.none = `calendarTableView`cell  don't follow `cornerRadius`

Case 4: Row `height` = 44 and `scrollPosition.middle` = `calendarTableView`cell don't follow `cornerRadius`

Case 5: Row `heigh`t = 60 and `scrollPosition.none` = `calendarTableView`cell DOES follow `cornerRadius`

Case 6: Row `height` = 60 and `scrollPosition.middle` = `calendarTableView`cell DON'T follow `cornerRadius` again..

I wouldn't mind row height of 60, but `scrollPosition`has to be.middle or I wouldn't see the current day row..

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I've searched other posts but I couldn't find anything that gave me a clue on what the problem was.
Many thanks as usual.
This is the `calendarTableView`function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...

        let date = datesArray[indexPath.row]
        print(date)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: date)

        cell.dayLabel.text = "\(String(describing: components.day!))" + " " + "\(dayNamesArray[components.weekday! - 1])"
        cell.cellWeekday = components.weekday!
        print("cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!)") // prints correct weekday

        cell.cellId = "\(String(format:"%04d", components.year!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.month!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.day!))"
        self.selectedDate = cell.cellId // used for time slots cellId
        print("##################### selectedDate in tableview is :\(self.selectedDate) ")

        // highlighting current day cell
        if indexPath.row == self.actualDay - 1 && self.actualMonth == self.displayedMonth {

            cell.dayLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3)

            // emulate user selecting the cell
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none) // changing to .middle makes the tableview go looping
            print(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   selected cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ")
//            self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)
//            self.actualWeekday = cell.cellWeekday! // nil error
            self.selectedDate = cell.cellId
//            calculateOpenTimeSlots()

        }
//        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
//        cell.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
//        cell.clipsToBounds = true
//        self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)
        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to select the today `row` but only scroll `calendarTableView`to have in that middle position instead. I also declare `row` `height` directly in `heightForRowAt`. `calendarTableView` now behaves as expected and cell is not directly selected, but highlighted as I actually wanted.
I hope that this will help others.
The final function is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarTableViewCell
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.dayLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.dayLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
        cell.dayLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        cell.dayLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        // Configure the cell...

        let date = datesArray[indexPath.row]
        print(date)

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: date)

        cell.dayLabel.text = "\(String(describing: components.day!))" + " " + "\(dayNamesArray[components.weekday! - 1])"
        cell.cellWeekday = components.weekday!
        print("cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!)") // prints correct weekday

        cell.cellId = "\(String(format:"%04d", components.year!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.month!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.day!))"
        self.selectedDate = cell.cellId // used for time slots cellId
        print("##################### selectedDate in tableview is :\(self.selectedDate) ")

        // highlighting current day cell
        if indexPath.row == self.actualDay - 1 && self.actualMonth == self.displayedMonth {

//            cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
            cell.dayLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor

            // emulate user selecting the cell
//            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
            print(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   selected cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ")
            self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)
//            self.actualWeekday = cell.cellWeekday! // nil error
            self.selectedDate = cell.cellId

        }

        return cell

    }
```